# COPY command issue

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-copy

I'm using this to read data into the table I created in Postgres 9.2:

```
COPY tagdata FROM 'C:/Filter112595/QF112595_3.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' 
    CSV HEADER FORCE_NOT_NULL;
```

Data types are `real`, `integer` and `date`.

I get this error:

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type real: "NULL"
> CONTEXT:  COPY tagdata, line 2, column residual: "NULL"
> ```

Before using `FORCE_NOT_NULL`, I had `NULL` as '' but changed it because of the different data types.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: What do the first two lines of the "QF112592_3.csv" file look like? Showing the table DDL would probably help too.

Comment: Seems like you have NULL in the file for a real type field.

Answer (score 2):

You've told PostgreSQL that no columns are null, so `NULL` in the column must mean a number. Since `NULL` isn't a valid floating point number, you get an error.

You haven't really given the information required to help you properly, but my guess is that you need to specify `FORCE_NOT_NULL` only for a subset of the columns. See the syntax for `copy`:

```
    FORCE_NOT_NULL ( column_name [, ...] ) |
```

In questions like this you really should provide a couple of lines of the CSV so we can see what's really going on, and when you make statements like:

> Before using FORCE_NOT_NULL, I had NULL as '' but changed it because of the different data types.

you need to *explain* that - *what* "different data types", why'd you need to change it, what problem you thought you were solving, links to any previous related SO questions, etc.